# (Follow Up) How to print out command-line arguments in X86-64 Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, command-line-arguments

I want to print out command line arguments out in x86-64 assembly(with AT&T syntax).

This is a followup question to my previous post on how simply to access these arguments. I also wanted to know how to print all command-line arguments to the console.

```
.globl main
main:
  push %rbp                        # rbp not used, for alignment only
  mov %rsp, %rbp

  mov %edi, %esi                   # move argc to second parameter register
  lea format_string(%rip), %rdi    # the format string is the first parameter
  xor %eax, %eax                   # 0 xmm registers used
  call printf@plt
  xor %eax, %eax                   # return 0 to behave nicely

  mov 16(%rbp), %rsi               # get argv[1] (pointer to first command line argument)
  mov (%rsi), %rdi                 # load the pointer to the first argument into %rdi
  lea arg_format(%rip), %rsi       # load argument format string
  xor %eax, %eax                   # 0 xmm registers used
  call printf@plt

  pop %rbp
  ret

.section .rodata
format_string: .string "Arguments: %d\n"
arg_format: .string "First Argument: %s\n"
```

Comment: You missed point (1) of Jester's answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76416529/how-to-print-the-number-of-command-line-arguments-in-x86-64-assembly): *That stack layout is for the initial entry point, not main.*  Again, compiler output for a C `main` would have made a working example for a normal function like `main`, as opposed to `_start`. (Although if you were writing a `_start`, you have too many dereferences.) See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) for more about looking at compiler output.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to get `argv` from `16(%rbp)` which doesn't make sense.  It's not on the stack.  It was the second argument to `main` so it was in `%rsi` on entry to the function.

Since `%rsi` is call-clobbered, we need to save it in a call-preserved register across the first `printf` call.  I've chosen `%rbx` below (`%rbp` would also have worked).  And since it is call-preserved we need to save and restore it at the beginning and end of our `main` function (this also happens to take care of stack alignment).

Since `%rbx` points to the start of the `argv` vector, or in other words its zeroth element `argv[0]`, we have to add 8 to point to `argv[1]`.  So `mov 8(%rbx), %rsi` will get it for us.

Also, your code had the argument order reversed on the second call to `printf`.

Here is a fixed version that works for me:

```
.globl main
main:
        push %rbx                       # %rbx is call preserved
        mov %rsi, %rbx                  # save argv in %rbx
        mov %edi, %esi                  # move argc to second parameter register
        lea format_string(%rip), %rdi   # the format string is the first parameter
        xor %eax, %eax                  # 0 xmm registers used
        call printf@plt

        mov 8(%rbx), %rsi               # argv[1] as second parameter
        lea arg_format(%rip), %rdi      # format string as first parameter
        xor %eax, %eax                  # 0 xmm registers used
        call printf@plt

        xor %eax, %eax                  # NOW this is the return value
        pop %rbx
        ret  

.section .rodata
format_string: .string "Arguments: %d\n"
arg_format: .string "First Argument: %s\n"
```

If you want to print all the arguments, then you need to write a loop.  You could add 8 to `%rbx` on each iteration to point to the next element of `argv`.  Load it into a register, test whether it is zero (i.e. null pointer), and conditionally jump out of the loop if not; otherwise print it.  I'll leave the implementation for you as practice.