# printf with float values - EAX less than the number of FP args?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

I saw this example code in a book. Is it wrong? The RAX register is loaded with the value 1 before printing the division's result, even though it is using three float values. I thought it would load RAX with 3 just like it did for printing the multiplication's result.

```
f_mul        db    "The float product of %f and %f is %f",10,0
f_div        db    "The float division of %f by %f is %f",10,0

; multiplication
movsd   xmm2, [number1]      ; double precision float into xmm
mulsd   xmm2, [number2]      ; multiply with xmm
        ; print the result
        mov   rdi,f_mul
        movsd xmm0, [number1]
        movsd xmm1, [number2]
        mov   rax,3 ; three floats
        call  printf
; division
movsd   xmm2, [number1]      ; double precision float into xmm
divsd   xmm2, [number2]      ; divide xmm0
        ; print the result
        mov   rdi,f_div
        movsd xmm0, [number1]
        movsd xmm1, [number2]
        mov   rax,1 ; one float
        call  printf
```

Comment: You're correct, that's a bug.  It happens to work anyway in glibc compiled by a GCC that isn't ancient, because GCC's code-gen for variadic functions changed to just checking if AL is 0 vs. non-zero before dumping all the regs.  Old GCC used to make code that did a computed jump based on AL, so it needed `num_args <= AL <= 8` like the ABI requires.  [printf gets stuck in an infinite loop with AL = 10 on x86-64 Linux with older gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61622435) .  Also, found a better duplicate: [Why does printf still work with RAX lower...?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71982459)