# NASM program doesn't print constant integer (macOS)

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, nasm, system-calls

I try to print `b`, but it prints nothing. Also I wanted to find length of `b` to hardcode it (because `dw`s have the same length), but it printed nothing too (that's why I created `lenlen` — len of `blen`, so that I can print `blen`). Don't pay attention to `k` and `a`, they are not used yet.

```
    global _main:
    section .data
b:  dw 10
blen: equ $-b
lenlen: equ $-blen
k:  dw 6
    section .bss
a:  resw 1
    section .text
_main:

    mov rax, 0x2000004
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, b
    mov rdx, blen
    syscall

    mov rax, 0x2000001
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

Comment: sys_write system call doesn't print numbers. It only prints ascii strings (and there isn't a system call that prints number). You will have to convert the number to a string and pass that string to sys_write.

Comment: @MichaelPetch to do it I just have to move contents of `b` to a register?

Comment: No, you need to convert it to a string. You need to build the string with the number in it and pass the address of that new string to sys_write. One way to convert a number to a string is repeated division by 10.

Comment: [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) has 64-bit code (and a Linux `write` system call; easily adapted to OS X's call number)

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm actually ok with using C functions, but when I try to use `printf` (or `_printf` for macs?), it says that `Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses`.

Comment: There is an algorithm to convert an integer to an ascii string in this answer stackoverflow.com/a/56483319/3857942 .

Comment: @MichaelPetch here they add/subtract '0' to convert to ascii: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_arithmetic_instructions.htm

Comment: That works if dealing with a single digit number. It doesn't work if you have more than 1 digit.

Comment: You can of course `call _printf` if you link libc: see [Why is %eax zeroed before a call to printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6212665) for AT&T syntax examples of the calling convention.