# What is the "sub $16, %rsp" instruction being used for?

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86-64, calling-convention

Let's take the following basic C function and the intentionally unoptimized assembly it produces:

```
int main() {
    int i = 4;
    return 3;
}
```

It produces the following (unoptimized) assembly, which all makes sense to me:

```
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    $4, -4(%rbp)
        movl    $3, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

However, as soon as I add in a function call, there are two instructions that I don't quite understand:

```
void call() {};
int main() {
    int i = 4;
    call();
    return 3;
}
```

```
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $16, %rsp     <-- why is it subtracting 16?
        movl    $4, -4(%rbp)
        movl    $0, %eax      <-- why is it first clearing the %eax register?
        call    call
        movl    $3, %eax
        leave
        ret
```

If the stackframe needs to be 16-byte aligned, how does the `subq $16, %rsp` help with that? Doesn't the initial `pushq %rbp` instruction already offset it by 8 and now it's at +24 ? Or what are the points of those two lines in question above?

Comment: It reserves space in stack. It’s not about alignment, it just needs space there. Right after it puts the variable `i` there, for example.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen ok, but it's an `int` so why doesn't it just reserve 4 bytes or so?

Comment: To keep the 16-byte alignment of the stack.

Comment: Regarding the stack alignment, keep in mind that a further 8 bytes were pushed by the `call` instruction that transferred control to `main`.  So relative to its value *before* the `call`, the stack pointer has moved down by 8+8+16=32 bytes and the 16-byte alignment is maintained.

Comment: @NateEldredge oh, that's helpful, I forgot that `main` is called by a wrapper program and goes through `_start` -- so that now makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first variant stores the local variable in the red zone, a 128 byte area below the stack pointer that is not changed by [signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)) handlers. The second variant cannot use the red zone because the `callq` instruction writes to the (original) red zone, clobbering the local variable stored there. (The called function could write to the original red zone as well, of course.)

`%eax` is set to zero because the function definition declares no prototype, so the compiler has to assume it is a variadic function. The `%eax` (actually `%al`) is used to [optimize the implementation of variadic functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58684613/8316315).

Comment: Indeed: C is not C++ and `void call()` isn't a declaration of a function with *no* arguments, it's a declaration of a function with *unspecified* arguments.  OP: You wanted to write `void call(void)` and then you'll see that instruction go away.

Comment: @Florian -- could you please explain what a "signal handler" is? Or perhaps link to where I might learn more about it.

Comment: It's essentially a userspace interrupt. The kernel pushes some state on the thread stack and invokes a user-defined routine. That's why the red zone would be overwritten if the kernel wouldn't preserve it in this context.